# Any idea where the additional printed None is coming from?

Tags: variables, printing, global, local

Hello am trying between local vs global variables and got the below code. When I run this code the following outputs are given. I thought the below code only asks for 2 outputs from the various print statements but am getting a "None" as well. Please can you let me know where this "None" is coming from? Thanks!

**CODE:**

```
x = 'global X'

def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    print (x)

print (test())
print (x)
```

**Output:**

```
local x
None
local x
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `test()` function, you have a print.

The 1st `local x` of you output is the one in the `test` function, 
then it tries to print the return of the `test` function, which is nothing, so it prints none. You could simply return x instead of printing it, like this:

```
def test():
    global x
    x = 'local x'
    return x
```

This way it won't print none.